# Tomcat - stdout file is very huge

Tags: tomcat, logging

I want to limit stdout file size inside Tomcat logs folder.

my questions are  :

1. I need to config extra logging configuration except
   `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=25000000`  ?
2. is it required apache service restart to take a effect changes ?

I want to add under the Java tab, in the Java Options section add the following:
`-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=25000000`

Already , defined below parameters in the Java Options section:

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\logging.properties
```

logging properties :

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat logs to the error file descriptor using `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` (not `java.util.logging.FileHandler`) which sends everything to `System.err`. Therefore there is no way to limit the size of the logs.

However you can in [**prunsrv**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) (usually renamed as **tomcat8.exe**):

1. Disable the redirection of `stdout/stderr` to any file by setting `--StdOutput` and `--StdError` to the empty string. The default `logging.properties` file distributed with Tomcat logs everything also to `catalina.<date>.log`, which is rotated daily, so Tomcat's logs will not be lost.
2. Set the `--StdOutput` and `--StdError` options to `auto`, which should rotate them daily, although I didn't test and it [doesn't seem to be implemented yet](https://github.com/apache/commons-daemon/blob/ff1c7eb20d90d4cf8bcd5534c24e8ed010ae63e0/src/native/windows/apps/prunsrv/prunsrv.c#L268)<sup>[1]</sup>.

You can change this setting also in the graphical interface **prunmgr** (usually renamed as **tomcat8w.exe**).

**Remark**: If you disable the redirection of `stdout/stderr` to a file, you should also disable the `ConsoleHandler` by modifying `logging.properties` from:

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to:

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

Check also whether your web applications don't use other logging frameworks than `java.util.logging` and modify the logging configuration (`log4j.properties` for Log4j 1.x, etc.) so that nothing is logged to the standard output/error.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> There is a long standing [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DAEMON-213) for this issue.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer.  which parameters require in the Java Options section inside tomcat8w.exe GUI?

Comment: Leave the standard ones (those you listed in your question). Change just the _"Logging"_ tab, `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties` and look if there are other logging frameworks used in your applications.

Comment: I have updated my question. you can see my logging properties.  is it enough `.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
`?

Comment: I would remove `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` since the same exact content is sent to the other handler. As explained `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` does not feature any rotation or maximum file size (since it doesn't know it logs to a file). The other handler is more configurable.

Comment: thanks again lastly , is it require restart service?

Comment: Unfortunately yes: most changes to `logging.properties` require a Tomcat restart. Some small changes might be done through JMX, but not handler configuration.